# combo box directive not triggered

Tags: combobox, angular-directive, kendo-ui-angular2

We have created a directive to do a validation of the input/ selected item must be exists in the combo box list. However, it's not working anymore after upgraded the package to 0.18.1 and implement the  [allowCustom]="true". It was working in the previous version 0.10.x.

The scenario is when user remove the entry from the combobox and enter a value again, the directive is triggered. But if user, append the content in the combobox, the directive is not triggered at all.

Please help. [Video attached](https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApYbexK0E545dGF20zlnsawlV1I)

[Sample Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwouN3dyERj6ZDhzNXRNSWlBV0k/view?usp=sharing) is Attached.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a plunkr?

Comment: Sample project is added and link provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns@0.18.x release.

I updated the demo to the latest official (0.21.x) and it seems fixed:
http://screencast.com/t/xyN8q9kR

Comment: We tested in different scenario  Steps 1. Select a country(i.e:Republic of China) 2. Straight away append characters 'abc' after selection without clearing the selection (i.e:Republic of Chinaabc). The error doesn't appear.